# How can I set vertical watermark on Image in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

**I want to set watermark on Image vertically.Like as below picture.**

[image]

**Here is my Watermark Code**

```
$config['source_image'] = '/path';
    $config['wm_text'] = 'WaterMark';
    $config['wm_type'] = 'text';
    $config['wm_font_size'] = '16';
    $config['wm_font_color'] = 'ffffff';
    $config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'bottom';
    $config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'left';
    $config['wm_padding'] = '20';

    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

    $this->image_lib->watermark();
```

Comment: using codeigniter's image manipulation class there is no in built functionality to achieve this. the best you could probably do is create a transparent image with the watermark in that position and use that instead of text.

Comment: then how to replace text on image.

Comment: just follow the docs for adding an overlay.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `overlay` image like this:

```
$config['source_image'] = 'source_image.jpg'; 
$config['wm_type'] = 'overlay';
$config['wm_overlay_path'] = 'overlay_watermark.png';
$config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'bottom';
$config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'left';

$this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
$this->image_lib->watermark();
```